# Regex Match in between Strings

Tags: regex, regex-group

I using Regex to extract a pattern which is of the form [a-zA-z][0-9]{8} Ex:K12345678
I need to extract this pattern from a string and this pattern should be matched properly
I tried the below but my testcase if failing for this scenario

This is my Regex /[a-zA-Z][0-9]{8}/g
phonne number:9978434276**K12345678**:My pattern

For this scenario it is failing.

My Sample Code

```
const expression = /[a-zA-Z][0-9]{8}/;
const content = "phone number:9978434276K12345678:My pattern"
let patternMatch = content.match(expression);
```

The expected output is K12345678.The Regex which I wrote does not handle this.

Comment: Testcase : "phonne number:9978434276K12345678:My pattern" . In this string the pattern is present but my regex pattern does not extract it.

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: Please add the tag for your language to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use String.match(Regex)

```
"9978434276K12345678".match(/[a-zA-Z][0-9]{8}/)
```

It returns an array of 4 elements: [`String coincidence`, `index`: Number, `input`: String, `groups`: undefined]

just stay with the element 0: `coincidence` and 1: `index of the match`.

and use this just to check that the string matches at least one

```
/Regex/.test(String)
/[a-zA-Z][0-9]{8}/.test("9978434276K12345678")
```

It will return true or false

**USE** expression without quotation marks

```
const expression = /[a-zA-Z][0-9]{8}/;
const content = "phone number:9978434276K12345678:My pattern"
let patternMatch = content.match(expression);
```